# Instagram iPhone Hooks iOS 11.2.5 instagram 29, feed not opening the file, but the camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, share, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

the project I have uses UIDocumentInteractionController to copy/share and image to Instagram, it worked fine for a while.

As soon as I selected the instagram app from the iOS share sheet. the image was open in the select filter section.

Recently, the image is now opened in a view with an x to close and two buttons, one to select stories and another one to select feed, if I select feed, then the camera roll is opened and the last picture is selected or the camera but the image I was sharing from my project disappears. I can not find if there is a change in hooks or the instagram documentation. [share sheet opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBbCa.png)

[instagram app opens the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h83If.png)
[if feed selected then the file or image is lost and only camera roll is avaiable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qwYc.png)

Comment: Can you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram seems to have fixed this issue in version **35.0.**

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing this behavior when sharing via UIDocumentInteractionController, it was previously working fine. Instagram may have broken something?

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.image, 1.0);

NSString *writePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"instagram.igo"];
if (![imageData writeToFile:writePath atomically:YES]) {
    [self activityDidFinish:NO];
    return;
}

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:writePath];
self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
self.documentController.delegate = self;
[self.documentController setUTI:@"com.instagram.exclusivegram"];

// Presentation logic
```